# Windows Media Player seamless looping of video

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, media-player

I am implementing a Windows Media Player into my WinForms application. axWindowsMediaPlayer is in the application and it is working fine, but my issue is that there is a black-screen flicker in between the playing of the video. But the odd thing is that it does not flash the black screen in between the first and second times playing the video. So, this leads me to believe it must be some sort of buffering or something in which during the first play it keeps up fine but thereafter is has problems keeping up with the loading and also playing of the video at the same time.

So, basically what I wondering is if the best fix would be to somehow completely cache the video, or somehow pause it as it loads it again, and maybe I have to go about this all based on a timer or something to that effect. In any case, please let me know what, if anything is known for a fix to this problem of the blackscreen flicker in between looping of a video in a Winforms embedded Windows Media Player.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to manually reset video current position using follow code. It will start video from beginning without any flicker.

```
AxWindowsMediaPlayer.Ctlcontrols.currentPosition = 0
```

Or use this within a timer tick event and when video is near end then manually play it from beginning like this.

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    If AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.currentPosition > AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.currentItem.duration - 0.01 Then
        AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.currentPosition = 0
    End If
End Sub
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.currentPosition > axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.currentItem.duration - 0.01)
            {
            axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.currentPosition = 0;
            }
    }
```

this code change currentPosition to 0 second when video running 0.01 milliseconds so that transition effect of black screen can be avoided

Comment: Please add explanation to your answer.